# Angular won't post data in api

Tags: angular

```
createAndStorePost(id: string, name: string, description: string,domain: string) {
   const postData: Post = {   id  , domain , name, description  };
    this.http.post<{ id: number, name: string , description: string , domain: string }
        (
          'https://hamaaa-ff9ee.firebaseio.com/',
           postData,
           {
            observe: 'response'
           }
        );
}}
```

is this code is right??
i want to post data in postman api

Comment: http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas   THIS IS MY API

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: @NicholasK it won't working i had tried

Comment: Are you getting an error? If you are, then [edit] your post and add the error details. If you aren't getting an error then your code isn't doing what you want it to do. In that case, [edit] your post and add what you want it to do and what it is doing now.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#sending-data-to-the-server

Answer (score 0):

I have just written how to send data to server in angular using HttpClient.

//This is my model to post

```
 product: BrandSetupModel = {
    id: 1,
    brandName: 'Apple',

  }

 this.saveBrandSetup(product)
  .subscribe((data: any) => {
    console.log(data);
  }, (error: any) => {
    console.log(error);
  }
  )

  saveBrandSetup(BrandSetup: BrandSetupModel) {
      return this._http.post('http://localhost:9094/'+ 'api/CrmBrandSetup/Create', BrandSetup, 
       this.requestOptions)
        .catch(this.errorHandler)
    }

requestOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('userToken'),

  })
};

errorHandler(error: Response) {
  console.log(error);
  return Observable.throw(error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### The theory

Let's start from the `post` definition of the `HttpClient` in angular

```
post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) : Observable<Response>
```

Does it look like your own implementation? No, so let's try to change it a bit

### The answer

```
createAndStorePost(id: string,name: string,description: string, domain: string) {
    // Create your Post Data (remember, second parameter)
    const postData: any = { id: number, name: string , description: string , domain: string};
    // No option, you just want to subscribe here
    this.http.post('https://hamaaa-ff9ee.firebaseio.com/',postData).subscribe(
        (result) => {
            // do stuff with the result
        }
    );
}
```

Noticed how I removed the observe options there? Put it back again if you want the following to happen:

> Tell HttpClient that you want the full response with the observe option:

```
getConfigResponse(): Observable<HttpResponse<Config>> {
  return this.http.get<Config>(
    this.configUrl, { observe: 'response' });
}
```

> Now HttpClient.get() returns an Observable of type HttpResponse rather than just the JSON data.

So with this option, you will not get JSON data, but a wrapper function.